# How to upgrade HornetQ version in JBoss 6?

Tags: configuration, upgrade, jboss6.x, hornetq

I am using JBoss-6.0.0 AS which by default comes with HornetQ-2.1.2 version but this version of HornetQ has many Iteration related bugs which are now resolved in HornetQ-2.2.5 version which by default comes with JBoss 7 AS.

I can't switch to JBoss 7 AS because I am already using many other services specific to JBoss 6 AS and it would be very risky for us to switch to JBoss 7 AS as of now.

Is there anyway by which I can upgrade HornetQ version in JBoss 6 AS ?
I tried with standalone HornetQ-2.2.5 by running it as different process, but with that JBoss JMX Console is not available.

Any suggestion is appreciated for this.
Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but with that JBoss JMX Console is not available.

use the jconsole from the JDK distribution.

You can either get a nightly build at http://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/view/JBoss%20AS/job/JBoss-AS-6.1.x/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/JBossAS_6_1/build/target/jboss-6.1.x.zip

Or this same question has been asked on the HornetQ user's forum:

http://community.jboss.org/message/616616?tstart=0#616616

- Delete message journal since the file format for 2.2.5 is not backwards compatible ($JBOSS_HOME/server//data/hornetq)
- Delete existing JMS Resource adapter jms-ra.rar folder under /deploy
  -Copy libs from HornetQ pack to $JBOSS_HOME/common/lib. The jars to copy are:

  - hornetq-bootstrap.jar
  - hornetq-core.jar
  - hornetq-jboss-as-integration.jar
  - hornetq-jms.jar
  - hornet-logging.jar
  - netty.jar
- Copy resource adapter from hornetq pack to /deploy and rename it from hornetq-ra.rar to jms-ra.rar (effectively replacing old version in step 2 above)
- Copy client libs from HornetQ pack to $JBOSS_HOME/client. The jars to copy are:

  - hornetq-core-client.jar
  - hornetq-jms-client.jar
  - netty.jar