# How to upgrade embedded HornetQ on JBoss 6.1.0.Final

Tags: jboss, upgrade, hornetq

I am running JBoss 6.1.0.Final with embedded HornetQ.
I want to upgrade HornetQ but keep the JBoss.
Is that possible, and how? What would  the latest compatible HornetQ version that can still work with JBoss 6.1.0Final?

Looking at this thread: [How to upgrade HornetQ version in JBoss 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771480/how-to-upgrade-hornetq-version-in-jboss-6)

I tried the following:
1- Download HornetQ 2.4.0, but wasn't sure what copy from the pack?
2- Download the latest JBoss AS 6.1.1Final and copies some jars, but not sure what version I deployed.

I  need at least version 2.3.0 or HornetQ, and I have no idea which version of HornetQ is deployed with the latest 6.1.1.Final !

Answer (score 1):

With JBoss EAP I would post your question to RedHat support. EAP 6.1 comes with HornetQ 2.3.1.Final, as you can see [here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673). 6.1.1 comes with 3.6.6. And you can see the version simply by looking at the log messages or inside the manifest.

Comment: +1 For pointing the where to find the HornetQ version. I found it in root.log and couldn't find a manifest. Not even mentioned in any documentation, release notes or readme files.

Comment: I dont have the binaries for EAP handy, but the hornetq implementation is in JAR files which contain the version number in the filename (and manifest) inside `wildfly-8.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\org\hornetq\main\hornetq-core-client-2.4.1.Final.jar`. Older JBoss versions had a different path, but all under modules/.

Comment: The "\modules" path is new since AS 7 onwards, older JBoss (e.g. 6.1.0) has different directory structure. But I did manage to see it in the root.log file. Thanks.